# Light Lab Misunderstanding. Please help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, waves, double-slit-experiment

For a Physics lab, this question was asked "As you learned, the wavelength and the separation of the sources affect the number of nodal lines produced. Using your results from steps 2 and 3, determine the effects of source separation on the nodal line structure for light." Can someone explain what the second sentence means?

Here is a photo of steps 2 and 3.
[image]

Comment: It would help to have a little more information about the experiment.

Comment: we have to measure the wavelength of light

Comment: How can one know what are the steps 2 and 3 ?

Comment: i posted a picture of it

Comment: I don't mind this homework question too much. The OP is asking what a question means, not how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The question likely wants to to qualitatively state how changing the slit separation affects  how the nodal line arrangement. For example, if the slits are closer together, what change do you see on the screen? What does this change tell you about the change in the nodal line arrangement?

Comment: what are nodal lines?